# Professional level news platform

Tags: open-source, software-development, cms, cross-platform

I am looking to buy/download a professional level (used by big corporation i.e. BBC, CNN, RT) news platform that can be used to build a high-grade news website. I have done some research and all I stumble upon is a range of WordPress plugins and some low quality scripts written in procedural PHP.

Are there any professional platforms on the market I could present to investors to ensure that my proposal is serious?

I am open to languages, but I prefer, although do not limit my options to modern frameworks like angular, react, riot, etc.

Comment: To get an answer on this site, you would have to describe what "professional-level" or "high-grade" means in terms of concrete features.

Comment: @Kodiologist, thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: [CNN uses WordPress](https://wordpress.com/notable-users/), so why doesn't WordPress meet your requirements?

Comment: Also, let me emphasize my previous request for concrete features. Which organizations use a piece of software isn't a feature of the software. This site is for finding software that does specific requested things, rather than for ranking software by popularity.

Comment: @Kodiologist, I am concerned with two issues with WordPress: 1. Proving it's security. 2. Proving its' reliability.